# Laggy ListView with Realm BaseAdapter?

Tags: android, asynchronous, adapter, realm, radix

In my app, I am using the RealmBaseAdapter with Android's Listview, and I'm having some issues with the general lagginess of the application. I was wondering if anyone had any general pointers as to how I can optimize my listview so that is does not appear laggy to the user. I tried routing most of my getView method through an AsyncTask, but, as much of my getView is the model interacting with the UI, pretty much everything had to be put on the onPostExecute thread. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you please show your adapter code?

Answer (score 1):

Following the advice here is a great first step: http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html

Otherwise this blog post by Romain Guy, also goes in depth with the tools you can use in order to find the root cause: http://www.curious-creature.com/2012/12/01/android-performance-case-study/

Without your adapter code, it is hard to say anything more concrete.